# What's the difference between setting open file limits in /etc/sysctl.conf vs /etc/security/limits.conf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-descriptors, ulimit, sysctl

I've read two separate ways of increasing the allowed open file count (I'm attempting to modify for root, if it matters).

One way is to update the settings in `/etc/security/limits.conf` with something like:

```
*                soft    nofile          500000

*                hard    nofile          500000

root             soft    nofile          500000

root             hard    nofile          500000
```

To make settings for the active shell, it looks like you can just do `ulimit -n 500000`, which wouldn't require a reboot or to logout/login, but may require restarting services (?).

---

The other option is to update `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
echo 'fs.file-max = 500000' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

To make settings for the active shell, we can do `sysctl -p`, and verify with `sysctl fs.file-max`.

So my question is, what's the difference? Is there one? I'm on `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is the scope, and how it's applied.  Open file limits set via sysctls apply to the entire system, whereas limits set via `/etc/security/limits.conf` apply only to things that meet the criteria specified there.  The other primary difference is that `/etc/security/limits.conf` limits are applied via ulimit, and thus can be changed more readily, while the sysctl limit is essentially setting up a memory allocation limit in the kernel itself.

As a general rule, you almost always want to use `/etc/security/limits.conf`, even if you're setting global limits with the wildcard match there, as it is a bit more reliable, and things usually fail more gracefully when hit with ulimit restrictions than hitting kernel memory allocation limits.